# What utilities should I put on an emergency recovery drive or SD card?

Tags: backup, recovery, utilities

I've recently made an emergency recovery SD card for my MacBook Pro. Right now, all it has is a clone of the internal drive's recovery partition, and an encrypted sparsebundle with my 1Password file. I'd like to throw on a few other utilities and tools in case of emergency. Free utilities preferred, but I'll happily throw down some money for a good app. Also, it's a 16GB card, and I want to keep 5GB free for the Mountain Lion download.

Answer (score 1):

Disk Warrior by Alsoft is the number one utility to buy, and its functions are completely unique.